# confusion over next() in restify vs express

Tags: express, restify

When called with `http://localhost:3000/foobar`, this works as expected - `next()` is called from the first route handler, and we get `'final'` from the second handler:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');

app.set('port', 3000);

app.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    return next();
});
app.get(/.+/, function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('final');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'));
```

However, similar code in restify doesn't seem to call `next()` in the first handler:

```js
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();

server.get('/foobar', function(req, res, next) {
    return next();
});
server.get(/.+/, function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('final');
});

server.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

My understanding from the [routing documentation](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#Routing) for restify is that calling `next()` will run the next handler in the chain, which matches how express works.

What am I missing, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that works. It does support chaining, but not on the routes themselves.
https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/issues/365